# Creating a mesh within spherical shell with gmsh 4.7.1

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to use `gmsh 4.7.1` to create a mesh within a 3D volume, that is a sphere with a concentric spherical hole (in other words, I have a spherical shell). In order to do so, I wrote the following `.geo` file:

```
// Gmsh project created on Wed Feb 17 15:22:45 2021
SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");

//+
Sphere(1) = {0, 0, 0, 0.1, -Pi/2, Pi/2, 2*Pi};
//+
Sphere(2) = {0, 0, 0, 1, -Pi/2, Pi/2, 2*Pi};
//+
Surface Loop(3) = {2};
//+
Surface Loop(4) = {1};
//+
Volume(3) = {3, 4};
//+
Physical Surface(1) = {1};
//+
Physical Surface(2) = {2};
//+
Physical Volume(3) = {3};
```

But, as soon as I create a 3D mesh by using the `3D` command in the `gmsh` gui, my **inner hole gets meshed too**, while I'd like to have no elements of the mesh within the hole.

What am I doing wrong? How can I obtain the desired result? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues at play here:

- [`Sphere` command](https://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Volumes), already creates a volume, not surfaces as you expect.
- due to the point above, the command `Surface Loop(3) = {2};` is assumed to create a surface loop from a volume, which is 1) not a supported operation. 2) will try to use the surface with the tag 2. It is unclear, what it will do in reality (as a surface with the tag `2` probably still exists).
- Thus, the `Volume` command gets some weird things as an input
- and it is all connected with the fact that the characteristic length is not setup, thus the mesh density is quite arbitrary.

If you insist on using the OpenCASCADE kernel, you probably want to use [boolean operations](https://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Boolean-operations).

Here is the code I have with an arbitrarily chosen characteristic length of 0.05 for all the points defining the solid spherical shell:

```
SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");

Sphere(1) = {0, 0, 0, 0.1, -Pi/2, Pi/2, 2*Pi};
Sphere(2) = {0, 0, 0, 1, -Pi/2, Pi/2, 2*Pi};

BooleanDifference(3) = { Volume{2}; Delete; }{ Volume{1}; Delete; };

Characteristic Length{ PointsOf{ Volume{3}; } } = 0.05;
```

Visualization from Paraview of the produced mesh with clipping:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That totally solved the issue. `gmsh` is not so easy to handle as I initially thought.